# PCB design review boost switching regulator

Tags: pcb-design, boost

I'm designing a board using the LTC7840 boost converter to boost from **+12V** to **+200V** in two stages (**+12V -> +50V** and then **+50V -> +200V**).

This is my simplified schematic and PCB design:

- U1: LTC7840
- L1, L2: Main Inductors
- Pencil is the trace/polygon on one layer
- **Red line** being the trace on the next adjacent layer
- SW1, SW2: Switching nodes

[image]

I don't have a program at the moment, I had to use pencil, paper and a couple of pens.

All design guidelines say that the switching loop should be keep as small/short as possible.

I have two questions:

1. How can I calculate the loop length?
2. How small/short should the loop be?

Comment: Please embed your diagrams into the question. What is your output load current minimum and maximum? What operating frequency are you running at? Please show a full schematic with MOSFET drive circuits and any feedback used to control the output? Loop length can only be measured when you have properly laid out the circuit board. As per the design guidelines, loop length should be as small as possible.

Comment: [LTC7840](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc7840.pdf) link

Comment: I kept the question as short as possible since this can be applied to many other designs using the same topology with a controller IC, a MOSFET and a feedback to get the desired voltage.
I didn't have a software here with me to layout the parts, that's why I draw a rough PCB layout (top) on a piece of paper :).
I took the schematic from this TI note (Figure 1-1) as it is short, widely being used and quite comprehensive. https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva372d/slva372d.pdf?ts=1672590308402